# XMLHttp won't send cookies

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, access-control

The problem is: I need to retrieve cookies from the server response using AJAX, using a specific registration API.

So I'm trying to fix this problem and I figured out much already:

I added `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to the PHP file` and I also added `xmlHttp.withCredentials = true` into the JS file.

Now, when I send a request to the server, i get "500 Internal Server Error".

I'm certainly doing something wrong. Please help if you know

Comment: Check webserver and php logfiles

Comment: Thanks, solved. I just had a typo in the header function ;(

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" **always** means "check webserver and php logfiles"!

Comment: But XMLHttp still refuses to accept cookies, what should I do?

Comment: Check request and response in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: Theyre is no "Set-Cookie header in server response."

Comment: Then you know where your problem lies.